# Win Tomcat "Use default" JVM error

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, jvm

I had the java 1.6 on my system and tomcat application which used "Use default" JVM option. After java 1.6 was replaced by newer one, tomcat service fails to start.

[Tomcat service checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIDnV.png)

I am trying to launch the windows service and get an error.

```
[994  prunsrv.c] [error] Failed creating java  
[1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
```

I've replaced java 1.6 by java 1.8 and updated the JAVA_HOME and Path environment variables to point to current 1.8 java. Also, i have updated the registry manually (some JAVA_HOME and other java-related entries), but it had no effect in case of tomcat service.

As per the tomcat howto:

> Use either auto (i.e. find the JVM from the Windows registry) or
>   specify the full path to the jvm.dll

If i use the second tip (full path to jvm), the tomcat service starts well.
But the thing i want to do is to fix the registry (in this case i suppose tomcat run well even if the "use default" is checked).

So, my question is

**Which entries in the registry are checked by tomcat when "Use default" option is active?**

Comment: If you open cmd and run "java -version" - will it show you newest version? Do you have java.exe in Windows/System32 folder (remove it if you have it there).

Comment: 1) It shows the new one
2) I dont have java.exe in System32 folder
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try checking

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

Edit the currentversion in the registry to point to the correct version. It should be either 1.8 in your case.